# change css style based on xmlhttp.responseText

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

Ok here is my problem. 
I am trying to change the css style of a text field based on the responseText of an xmlhttpRequest using jQuery. If the company name is already taken the php file will echo "Company Name Already Taken." and I want the comp_stat box background to turn red. If the company name is unique the php file will echo "Company Name Ok" and I want the comp_stat box background to turn green.

this is the javascript - the selected text is the part that's not working.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
        document.getElementById("comp_stat").value = xmlhttp.responseText;

        /*Not working part*/
        if(xmlhttp.responseText == 'Company Name Already Taken.'){
            document.getElementById("comp_stat").style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
        if(xmlhttp.responseText == 'Company Name OK!'){
            document.getElementById("comp_stat").style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }
        /*----------------*/
}
```

been scratching my head for hours on this, it's probably a simple fix... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The code looks like it should work, although it could be refactored a bit to store the reference to the text field and the response text in variables. Are you certain that the text coming back matches what you're expecting? No leading spaces or anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

> The part you highlighted does not seem to have any problem.

However, maybe it is somewhere else in your code have error. I suggest you to use web inspectors or debuggers to debug. I really like Chrome's Developer Tools (it is really Apple's) it is really easy to use. It will show errors if there is any and you can also see the line number.
[image]

> It will show where the error is. Very useful.

Comment: I only wish that in every other way (than JavaScript debugging) it was as good as Firebug. That goes doubly for the new Firefox inspector thing. Why do they insist playing the "not invented here" game to no benefit, when something much better, with reasonable licensing terms, already exists!?